# jQuery and AJAX Loading

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am making a page that when you click on a "story" it loads the text and the media for that story, I have a seperate PHP script for the story text and the media (video or image) loading. both scripts work and actually it all works.

My problem is that when you click the story it is supposed to load the text, and then slide the media down when it's loaded However, it slides down even when the text is still loading.

newspaper.nmyster.co.uk/ is the site in question. click on the vimeo story on the left and see what I mean.

The code for the AJAX that loads the story and media is:

```
$.ajax({
  url: './scripts/storyLoader.php?storyid='+storyId,
  success: function(result){
    $('#storycontainer').hide();
    $('#loading').remove();
    $('#storycontainer').hide(0).html(result).fadeIn(1000);
    }
});
$.ajax({
  url: './scripts/mediaLoader.php?storyid='+storyId,
  success: function(result){
    $('.martefact').hide();
    $('#loading').remove();
    $('.martefact').html(result).slideDown(1000);
    }
});
```

Basically, I only want the media div to slide down once the video or image has finished loading.

Thanks

Comment: People with slower connections may think something is not working if they have to wait.

Comment: hmmm... well this is for a project for Uni, so I wont have to worry about that really... i just want to do it for asthetics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use something like this:

```
var requestHandle;
function loadPage(url, vars) {
  //cancel pending
  if (requestHandle!=null)
      requestHandle.abort();

  //load page..
  requestHandle = $.get(url, vars, function(data) {
        $('#storycontainer').hide();
        $('#loading').remove();
        $('#storycontainer').hide(0).html(data).fadeIn(1000);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your request is asynchronous. It means that the script won't wait for data to load before executing the aesthetics bit.
You need to add async: false to your $.ajax call (look up other options over at jQuery documentation). That way, browser will wait for data to arrive first before executing the rest of JS.

Comment: I thought the success function is only called **after** some data arrived from the server?

Comment: Try with async: false and you'll notice the difference. I'd love to explain what's happening but my time is limited at this point, you might want to try to google what's going on with the success function and async / sync calls.

Comment: I hope I got that right, if async is false, code execution will stop until the data arrives and then calls the success function but at the same time blocking everything else! If async is true, normal code execution will continue but the success function will be called once the data arrived... so I don't think that this really is a solution, @nmyster have you tried it?

Answer (score 1):

What does your `mediaLoader.php` script do? Does it just check the database whether there are any media entries for the given story and if so format them properly and output them? Because currently I don't think you can slide down after the video is completely loaded, since you are embedding a vimeo video container, which handles the loading of the video itself and you have no access to it...

Comment: mediaLoader will, if its a video, get the details of the video and then embed it, i thought that might be a issue :/

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an 'on complete' callback function on the first animation.

Have a look [jQuery api documentation for .fadeIn()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/)

It should look something like:

```
$('#book').fadeIn('slow', function() {
    // Code to run after animation completed...
});
```